# How to get IPv6 routing table on Windows 2008+ using WMI

Tags: windows, routes, wmi, ipv6

Is there any way to get the IPv6 routing table using WMI for Windows 2008 and up?

By following this page: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822883(v=vs.85).aspx), there isn't any class that offers this data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer, the `MSFT_NetRoute` class from WMIv2 provider. This is only a partial fix, since it works only on Windows 8, Server 2012 and up.  :(